# Eliminar espacios en blanco JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper

Como puedo eliminar los espacios de los `textField` en `jasper` `report`.

Estoy utilizando `trim()` pero no me funciona

```
"+($P{VALOR1} != null ? " "+$P{VALOR1}.trim(): "") +
```

Gracias de antemano, un saludo

Comment: ¿Los espacios en blanco al principio y final de la cadena?

Comment: Tengo una cadena que viene de base de datos y tiene espacios en blanco, quisiera eliminarlos, esos espacios pueden ser tanto al principio como al final

Comment: Con el método `trim()` debería funcionar. Lo que veo es que el ejemplo que has puesto allí, le concatenas un espacio en blanco al principio de la variable que tiene el `trim`.

Comment: Si, necesito un espacio en blanco para separar el texto del valor, pero al final me pone muchos espacios en blanco, se que es tema de datos pero necesitaría poder encontrar una solución

Comment: ¿Y si lo haces a nivel de base de datos? En SQL SERVER sería algo como `LTRIM(RTRIM(nombre_de_tu_campo))`